# How can set number format for asp:label with CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net

I need to set label as separate numbers with using CSS not code behind.
I have already this code and it's work fine :

```
TextBox1.text= String.Format("{0,0:N0}", val(TextBox1.text))
```

But problem is i have alot of these labels and i can't set this format to all of them one by one, is there any solution i can do it with CSS?

This my number 1600000 and i like to show my number like this 1,600,000

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what you have and what you want? Just give us some input and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this `jquery mask plugin`

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.js

and apply it as below

```
$('.txt').mask("#,000", {
    translation: {
        '.': {
            pattern: /[.]/,
            fallback: '.'
        },
    },
    reverse: true
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1mdjmdv/)

Comment: I'm not pro in jquery but i think your code change all textbox to separate number format and i don't want to change all of them

Comment: you can apply `txt` class to those text boxes that you want to change